# Android toolbar - detect partial hide

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've implemented hide/show of the `Toolbar` with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`. I'm using `RecycleView` inside my fragment and all works fine.

But I've noticed some cosmetic issue - when I scroll the list for a bit, `Toolbar` doesn't hide completely. You can see this at the screenshot:[image: example]

I've tried to do the same in Google Play, and it detects such situations and either restores full `Toolbar` or hides it, showing only tabs.